# Buttons seems slightly lower than text

Tags: html, css

So when using HTML/CSS, buttons seem slightly lower (maybe 5-10px) than the text.

Why is this? Is there anyway to prevent this? I would like my buttons to be on the same level as text, without hanging below.

What methods do I use to accomplish this?

Comment: Example...? Most likely you need to set the CSS `vertical-align:` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <html>
    <body>

    <p>Hello world
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button></p>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1) Don't see an alignment problem in firefox or chrome. 2) This is not the right way to fix alignment issues. You should use css for that type of thing.  -1'd